# GOGS secret key

Tags: git, drone.io, gogs

I'm trying to integrate the Drone CI server with the GOGS Git server.

There's a pretty clear document on how to do so here: http://readme.drone.io/setup/config/gogs/

...which indicates I need the following configuration:

```
[gogs]
url = "http://gogs.drone.io"
secret = "c0aaff74c060ff4a950d"
```

Where does this secret come from? I can't seem to find it in GOGS anywhere.

Comment: Maybe from a procedure similar to http://readme.drone.io/setup/config/github/?

Comment: Thanks @VonC, got me on the right track - looks like tokens can be generated in GOGS at `/user/settings/applications`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That secret key "`c0aaff74c060ff4a950d`" seems to be the same all over the doc.
In [config/github](http://readme.drone.io/setup/config/github/), you can see that key generated through a registration process.

Similarly, the [OP Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385273/steve) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272107/gogs-secret-key/32274158#comment52427140_32272107):

> looks like tokens can be generated in GOGS at `/user/settings/applications`

Comment: Anticlimax - turns out the secret isn't actually required. (Thanks http://kevinlaw.info/blog/open-source-continuous-deployment/)  There's quite a few other settings in the "generate" key, but I'll decipher them another day.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Aha! Look what I found while digging around in `gogs/custom/conf/app.ini`.  I haven't had time to test it, but this looks to be the answer.