# GOGS Secret Key Usage Context / Process

Tags: gogs

This question is similar to this question:
[GOGS secret key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272107/gogs-secret-key)

However the post does not really confirm whether this key is the right key or whether the right key to use is a personal access token that can be generated via the UI.

Also I'm wondering what this `secret-key` is for in general?  The description does provide an answer, but what would be the context / process for using it:

```
SECRET_KEY: Global secret key for your server security, you’d better change it (will generate a random string every time you install).
```

TIA,
Ole